# AFHTTPClient requestWithMethod ParameterEncoding

Tags: ios, http-post, afnetworking, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to use AFNetworking for a HTTP Post method with some parameters and two values have the same parameter. I tried out:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", @"value3", @"param3", @"value4", @"param3", nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/index.php" parameters:params];
```

I used Charles Proxy and figured out that the value4 was missing in my request.

Then I tried:

```
NSString *parameter = @"param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param3=value4";
[request setHTTPBody:[parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And this worked.

Now I want to know if I am doing something wrong with AFNetworking or is this a bug of AFNetworking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not with AFNetworking but with NSDictionary. You cannot have two entries with the same key.

In this case it means:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", @"value3", @"param3", @"value4", @"param3", nil];
```

should be replaced the following

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", @"value3,value4", @"param3", nil];
```

Combining the two values for the one key.

Another way of combining arguments in one key is using a NSArray. For example:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value3",@"value4",nil], @"param3", nil];
```

Comment: Of course. I didn't think about that, but it's obvious. `-(NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method 
                                      path:(NSString *)path 
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters` needs a NSDictionary. Is there a way to produce the parameter string mentioned above with a NSDictionary ?

Comment: @KaiOe No, there is no way to have duplicate entries for keys in this way. If you need this, either build and set the POST body manually (as you did before), or, if the parameter is expecting an array (which it probably should, since you're defining multiple values), encode those in an array in the parameters dictionary.

Comment: Yes, the parameter expects an array. This works good: `NSArray *xjxargs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value3", @"value4",nil]; NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: xjxargs,@"param3"];` Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Typo, use param4 not param3 for last key value.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", @"value3", @"param3", @"value4", @"param3", nil]
```

Corrected one

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"param1", @"value2", @"param2", @"value3", @"param3", @"value4", @"param4", nil]
```

Comment: This is not a typo. I want to use param3 for value3 and value 4. This is because param3 is an array. Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177815/post-multiple-parameters