# Post local image file on tumblr via API with perl

Tags: perl, api, tumblr

I've been messing around with the tumblr API with perl and have gotten several functions to work.

However, I can not get local image files to upload via perl.

Here is my code that works for URLs

```
    use LWP::Authen::OAuth;
    use JSON;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use strict;
         my $ua = LWP::Authen::OAuth->new(
             oauth_consumer_key => 'xxx',
             oauth_consumer_secret => 'xxx',
             oauth_token => 'xxx',
             oauth_token_secret => 'xxx',
     );




    my $response;
    $response = $ua->post( 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/mytumblr.tumblr.com/post', [
         type    => 'photo',
         url    => 'http://www.example.com/mypic.jpg' ,
         caption => 'Test image 1',
     ]);


    if ($response->is_success) {
      print "it worked";
    }
    else {
     print "it did not work \n \n \n \n";
     print $response->as_string;
   }
```

However, when i substitute "url" for "data" in the post parameters (as instructed in their API description here - http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting), I keep getting an error response from tumblr. I have tried several ways of entering the "data" parameter - as a path to the file, as a binary representation, as a URL encoded binary representation, as a url encoded base64 binary representation, stuck ech one of those values as a sole element in an array - I have tried all, and with each one I get a error message back from tumblr.

So, can someone please show me how to upload a local image file to tumblr?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Connection: close Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 21:48:31 GMT Server: nginx Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Client-Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 21:48:31 GMT Client-Peer: 66.6.40.14:80 Client-Response-Num: 1 Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL" Set-Cookie: tmgioct=519402aea446110439257710; expires=Sat, 13-May-2023 21:48:30 GMT; path=/; httponly {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Error uploading photo."]}} `

Comment: try removing the caption part - does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the tumblr API, but a quick googling found me this example: https://gist.github.com/derekg/1198576

I would try

```
$response = $ua->post( 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/mytumblr.tumblr.com/post', [
     type    => 'photo',
     'data[0]'    => $file_contents , ## LWP::Useragent should automatically urlencode this
     caption => 'Test image 1',
 ]);
```

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/177866/810448, it's possible that "data[]" would also work in this situation.

I would also consider adding 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to the request headers, if LWP::Useragent is not doing it already.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either - however this time I seem to be getting the following error:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized
  Connection: close
  Date: Thu, 16 May 2013 17:48:56 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Length: 60
  Content-Type: application/json
  Client-Date: Thu, 16 May 2013 17:48:59 GMT
  Client-Peer: 66.6.40.14:80
  Client-Response-Num: 1
  Client-Warning: Missing Authenticate header
  P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"
  Set-Cookie: tmgioct=51951c0b8ea0630258123660; expires=Sun, 14-May-2023 17:48:59
  GMT; path=/; httponly
  X-Tumblr-Usec: D=3649265

  {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}

Comment: also - two follow up questions - what do you use to get the file contents? And how do you set the content type in the UA post? I have tried several methods for each (File::Slurp, my $imagepath = 'C:\scripts\vega1.jpg';
open (IMAGE, $imagepath) or die "$!";

my $raw_string = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };) - for file uploads, using $ua->default_header(''Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );, or specifyin it as a parameter in the POST request - all are coming up empty. I am honestly a little confused